# How can I create a database where entries are compressed files searchable by index?

Tags: index, compression

I am trying to design a database solution for logging where the search indices are dates (days), and the values are zipped files. I am doing this because the sheer number of logs I am processing is too great to simply store in a database. The zipped files would be all logs within the date (day) index. Once a user queries for a date, I would like to be able to query the logs associated with that date. This would require the program to uncompress the zipped file and provide parameters for the log once the user specifies the date.

Or, is there way (similar to zgrep) to search through compressed files and get corresponding date values?

I could find no information on this online. I am open to anything, relation or non relational databases.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? I've just seen your other comment about Linux and mongodb. You might try looking at [PostgreSQL and TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-toast.html) and check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801416/text-compression-in-postgresql) - look at out-of-line. Caveat - I've never used this.

Comment: You might also want to check out Oracle [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-securefiles-084075.html) - mucho dinero but possibly worth it given the price of implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tested the lz6 compression level?  lz6 provides less overall compression but it has a index on values which you can pull out without going through the overhead and cost of uncompressing the whole file.  I

If you cannot give up any compression at all, have you tried a simple json document store DB such as Mongo?  I feel using filestream in SQL Server might be overkill but it depends on your environment.  It seems like you're a linux shop from the terminology used, is that correct?

I feel you can use any DBMS to store the simple values such as customerid, date, and filepath then pass the filepath over to your app.  It depends on what solutions you already have in place or which you're very comfortable with that aren't overkill.  For example, Hadoop or something complex would be crazy for this but a key value store DB might be perfect.  Maybe you can make the zip files have the customer id or something in it and only store the date (key) and path (value) in your document store.

Comment: I cannot find anything on lz6 compression, is there a resource you can refer me to? Correct, I am planning on implementing this on a Linux machine. I very much like Mongo and would like to go with it as a solution, but I don't see how to incorporate zipped files in docs. Ideally I would like to have each document have index information and a reference to a zip file. The question is, once the user specifies the date index, and therefore gets the zip reference, how could he further search the log params in the zip file?

Comment: Very interesting, I can't find anything on it either now. Weird! I learned about it a few years ago in a Hadoop discussion group in Google, and I found a lossless LZ4 reference but not a lossly LZ6 reference.  I'll keep looking.  Here's the LZ4 reference if it helps.  Essentially you'd want a compression format that let's you "query" the index that would be the date field, then pull out that identifying file/record from the compressed folder.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ4_%28compression_algorithm%29

Comment: You wouldn't put the zipped file in a mongo doc.  It could be a nightmare if done wrong and you have a 10MB doc limit in Mongo.  What you would do is have the file pointer in Mongo.  Then you would pull that out, store it as a variable or directly pass it to your app as the path to unzip the file.  A python package could do that pretty cleanly.